# Bold Terminal window title using zsh using xterm-kitty

Tags: shell, zsh

I have been able to change the terminal title using the following code in ~/.zshrc. I do not really understand escape sequences.
The code is:

```
precmd () {echo -ne "\033]0;${PWD/#$HOME/~}\007"}
```

I do not know what exactly `\033]0;` and `\007` is doing in the string. I tried googling the code but nothing comes up that is of relevance. I want to understand what it does. I also want to make the text bold.

In my attempt to make it bold, I visited the webpage: https://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting

Where I found out the escape sequence to make it bold is \e[1m:

```
echo -e "Normal \e[1mBold \e[21mNormal"
```

So, I tried the following:

```
precmd () {echo -ne "\033]0;\e[1m${PWD/#$HOME/~}\e[21m\007"}
```

but it did not make the characters bold. I assumed that `\003]0;` sets the position of printing so I kept it.

Comment: You shouldn't be hard coding terminal control sequences at all: they're different depending on which terminal program you use, so the only reliable approach is to look them up at runtime with `tput` or a similar tool for doing lookups in the terminfo database; that way your terminal can select the sequences used to communicate with it, and terminals with fancier features can advertise those features while less-capable terminals are still handled gracefully.

Comment: That said, questions about configuring or customizing your interactive shell are generally better suited to our sister site [UNIX.se]; Stack Overflow is narrowly focused on writing software.

Comment: BTW, in shells that more strictly follow the POSIX grammar, spaces after `{` and before `}` are mandatory. It's a good habit, then, to leave that whitespace. (One also needs a command separator, such as `;` or a newline, before `}`).

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Fe_Escape_sequences). _ESC ]_ starts a so-called _Operating System Command_ (OSC), the effect of which is dependent on the terminal emulator being used. As you can see on the page I linked to, `xterm` for instance uses the OSC _0_ to set the window title. If your terminal is xterm-compatible, it should do the same.

Comment: my terminal is xterm-kitty. it set the title but does not make it bold. I have set shell-integration in kitty.conf to no title as well before hand. but it makes it bold i remove \033]0; and \007. it shows bold as normal output